# Does it make sense to mix button types between state changes in this case?

Tags: email, gdpr

We are in the process of placing unsubscribe options in our edit users screens and I wanted to make the unsubscribe process instant, rather than require the user to click to save at the bottom of the page in order to affect the change. Should I move the unsubscribe to it's own section and toggle between two buttons, or just stick with making the unsubscribe instant and leave the subscribe interaction as-is?

**User is subscribed:**
[image: subscribed state]

**User clicks unsubscribe:**
[image: confirm modal]

**User must click the checkbox AND save changes to resubscribe:**

[image: unsubscribed state]

Comment: This is interesting. But a part of me says place it in it's own section as the AI indicates that even when they click "unsubscribe" that users might feel compelled to click "save changes" to implement the unsubscribe. It's a tad bit confusing, because everything else in the pages requires the "save changes" but that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be confusing for the user because it's a button, much like the save button but sits amongst inputs that require you to click save changes. My recommendation would be to either move the button to a different section, or change it to a switch that falls inline with the other input styles and make the user click save button.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up moving it to a box under the password change box and added a popup confirming that the user was unsubbed, to reinforce that there was no need to save changes